# AS3 Error Property 5 not found on String and there is no default value

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm newbie to integrate Flash. I am having an issue with a project. I am working on in flash Cs5.5. Following is my stack and code.could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

My stack error:

```
ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property 5 not found on String and there is no default value.
    at SceneQues_fla::MainTimeline/randomRange()
    at SceneQues_fla::MainTimeline/ques()
```

My code:scene 1:

```
     stop();

     var question:Array =["slide2","slide3","slide4","slide5"];
     function randomRange(array) {
     var i = array.length,
         j = 0,
         temp;


    while (i--) {

        j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i+1));
        temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;

    }

    return array;
}

start_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ques);
function ques(event:MouseEvent):void
{   

     var randomRange = String(randomRange(question[0]));
     gotoAndStop(randomRange);
}




    /* start_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ques  ); 
     function ques(e:MouseEvent):void
{
```

I am using six different scene in my flash. I already declared frame label in my scene. `slide2` is scene 2, `slide3` is scene 3, `slide4` is scene 4, `slide5` is scene 5.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First, your function:

```
function randomRange(array) {
```

And your input for that function:

```
var randomRange = String(randomRange(question[0]));
//                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^ This value is the string "slide2".
```

Notice how you're providing a string to a function that is expecting an array.

Comment: I need one array element scene while random number function that's why i used this var randomRange = String(randomRange(question[0])); Is it right or wrong?

Comment: @SathisJo Wrong, perhaps you meant `randomRange(question)`?

Comment: if i used String(randomRange(question)); meanwhile i had this error Error #2109: Frame label slide3,slide5,slide4,slide2 not found in scene Scene 1...what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

In your function ques(), you invoke: *RandomRange(question [0])*, but *question[0]* is *slide2*, the first element of your array *question*.

Your argument is a `String` instead of an `Array`. So your variable *i* gives the length of *slide2* and you are using a loop to go through this String as shown below, causing the same error:

```
var myString:String = 'slide5';
var i:int = myString.length; // 6
while (i--)
{
    trace(i); // 5 4 3 2 1 0
    trace(myString[i]); // first iteration (5) causes the error message.
}
```

Your code should be like that:

```
var questions:Array = [['slide2','scene2'],
                       ['slide3','scene3'],
                       ['slide4','scene4'],
                       ['slide5','scene5']];

var len:int = questions.length; // 4

start_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ques);

function ques(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var k:int = Math.floor(Math.random() * len);
    gotoAndStop(questions[k][0], questions[k][1]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay helloflash.But i used your code by the time that i had this error ArgumentError: Error #2109: Frame label slide4 not found in scene Scene 1.
 at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndStop()
 at Randomques_fla::MainTimeline/ques()

Comment: @Sathis Jo You have to create your labels by clicking on a frame of your main timeline and using the Label menu in the Properties panel.